# How to interpret objective-c type specifier (e.g. returned by method_copyReturnType())?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Given I have a type specifier as returned by method_copyReturnType(). In the GNU runtime delivered with the GCC there are various methods to work with such a type specifier like `objc_sizeof_type()`, `objc_alignof_type()` and others.

When using the Apple runtime there are no such methods.

How can I interpret a type specifier string (e.g. get the size of a type) using the Apple runtime **without** implementing an if/else or case switch for myself?

**[update]**

I am not able to use the Apple Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, you'll need to bake that info into your binary. just create a function which returns the sizeof and alignof in a struct, supports the types you must support, then call that function (or class method) for the info.

The program below shows you that many of the primitives are just one character. So the bulk of the function's implementation could be a switch.

```
static void test(SEL sel) {
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], sel);

    const char* const type = method_copyReturnType(method);

    printf("%s : %s\n", NSStringFromSelector(sel).UTF8String, type);

    free((void*)type);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        test(@selector(init));
        test(@selector(superclass));
        test(@selector(isEqual:));
        test(@selector(length));

        return 0;
  }
}
```

and you could then use this as a starting point:

```
typedef struct t_pair_alignof_sizeof {
    size_t align;
    size_t size;
} t_pair_alignof_sizeof;

static t_pair_alignof_sizeof MakeAlignOfSizeOf(size_t align, size_t size) {
    t_pair_alignof_sizeof ret = {align, size};
    return ret;
}

static t_pair_alignof_sizeof test2(SEL sel) {
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], sel);
    const char* const type = method_copyReturnType(method);
    const size_t length = strlen(type);

    if (1U == length) {
        switch (type[0]) {
            case '@' :
                return MakeAlignOfSizeOf(__alignof__(id), sizeof(id));
            case '#' :
                return MakeAlignOfSizeOf(__alignof__(Class), sizeof(Class));
            case 'c' :
                return MakeAlignOfSizeOf(__alignof__(signed char), sizeof(signed char));
            ...
```

Comment: So the answer is: There is no way to do this without implementing it by myself. Correct?

Comment: @Tilo I've done some silly things with the runtime - there is no free solution that I know of, but the solution in my answer can be implemented quite easily if you know the types you must support. Of course, you can also wait and see if you get a more appropriate answer.

Comment: @Tilo - added a demo for this

Comment: I have already a self-made implementation and I want to get rid of it. Since the GCC runtime brings one I thought that the Apple runtime would provide something similar. But the only things regarding this I found in the Apple runtime sources are commented out :(.

Comment: Ok - then perhaps somebody will offer a better solution?

Comment: Maybe … I'll wait for it and when nothing comes up I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you're looking for [`NSGetSizeAndAlignment`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSGetSizeAndAlignment):

> Obtains the actual size and the aligned size of an encoded type.
>
> ```
> const char * NSGetSizeAndAlignment (
>    const char *typePtr,
>    NSUInteger *sizep,
>    NSUInteger *alignp
> );
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>   Obtains the actual size and the aligned size of the first data type represented by `typePtr` and returns a pointer to the position of the next data type in `typePtr`.

This is a Foundation function, not part of the base runtime, which is probably why you didn't find it.

***UPDATE:*** Although you didn't initially mention that you're using Cocotron, it is also available there. You can find it in Cocotron's Foundation, in [NSObjCRuntime.m](http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.m).

Obviously, this is much better than rolling your own, since you can trust it to always correctly handle strings generated by its own runtime in the unlikely event that the encoding characters should change.

For some reason, however, it's unable to handle the digit elements of a method signature string (which presumably have something to do with offsets in memory). [This improved version, by Mike Ash](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure/blob/master/MABlockClosure.m) will do so:

```
static const char *SizeAndAlignment(const char *str, NSUInteger *sizep, NSUInteger *alignp, int *len)
{
    const char *out = NSGetSizeAndAlignment(str, sizep, alignp);
    if(len)
        *len = out - str;
    while(isdigit(*out))
        out++;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that I do not have general access to the Apple Foundation since it only exists for Apple products :). The project I am working on is Cocotron (an alternative to the Foundation). So I can't use Foundation methods.

Comment: @Tilo: The framework you're using is a **pretty big condition** that you probably should've included in your question to start with. The same function is, however, available in Cococtron. See my edit.